# JetBrains Rider - Generate Java like getter/setter?

Tags: c#, getter-setter, jetbrains-ide, rider

Does anyone know how to convert the C# getter and setter to a java-like getter and setter pattern using the Rider IDE?

Convert this:

```
    public Transform List
    {
        get { return list; }
        set { list = value; }       
    }
```

to this

```
public Transform GetList() { return this.list; }
public SomeClass SetList(Transform list) { this.list = list; return SomeClass; }
```

This would be usedful for chaining setters in a fluent builder pattern.

Comment: My question to you would be: why?. My assumption is this does not exist in Rider because it is not the accepted way of doing getters and setters in c#

Comment: `those weird C# getter and setter` The thing you are proposing would be weird in the context of C#.

Comment: @Turing85 Because the question contains java code... Because i like it more that way... never liked those c# getter and setter and im mainly programming in java, so its easier to switch between languages...

Comment: I wouldn't expect any tool to have this functionality built in, since this is something custom just for you.  You're going to need to build something for this, either as an extension of the tool you're using, or an extension of another tool, or a custom tool of your own.

Comment: @genaray "*Because the question contains java code... Because i like it more that way...*" - I am no expert on C#, but it is illogical to assume that Java-code works in C# (unless, of course, you use some advanced polyglot compiler or the languages are in this part identical on accident). Anyway, if you do not like C#, then don't use it.

Comment: `Because i like it more that way...` Alas, tooling is optimised to create **real** properties (which your code does not). No one working in C# would want to _encourage_ your idea.

Comment: I guess what everyone here is trying to tell you is... Having a personal preference is fine, and nobody here has any judgements either way.  But expecting C# tools to follow Java conventions is unrealistic.  And it is our professional recommendation to follow C# conventions when writing C# code so the code is more idiomatic and understandable.  (Think of it in reverse... If you're on a Java project and another developer insists on writing code "like C#", how successful do you expect that project to be?)

Comment: It isn't **just** a preference though. The proper code creates a .NET property. The Java style in C# doesn't (this is not a point of debate - it just doesn't). That will likely break JSON serialisation etc etc. I want the OP to be super clear. **This is a really bad idea.**

Comment: One note to all the downvoters: perceiving the subject of a question to be "silly" isn't necessarily the same as asking a bad question. So please ask yourself first if you intend to downvote because a question is off low quality, or just because you disagree with the OP. And just saying: disagreement isn't a reason for a downvote.

Comment: @mjwills One can spend a lot of time on meta stackoverflow and read questions about when why to downvote. The OP not coming ... well: when there is a need for clarification, then not answering is bad. Not sure what the community thinks about "not commenting on comments" though ;-)

Comment: It just sounded like there as an authoritative list of valid reasons for downvoting (given `disagreement isn't a reason for a downvote`). 'Reading lots of meta stackoverflow' is not my idea of a good time - but if you can point us to a list it would be helpful. `Not sure what the community thinks about "not commenting on comments" though` If someone asks a question, and fails to engage meaningfully and constructively with those who are trying to help them, that seems a fair reason to downvote (unless the list says otherwise). Note - I didn't downvote the OP in this specific case.

Comment: There are valid reasons to use setters in C# code in a class. If you are creation a builder for example, the fluent builder that uses chain accessors cannot be created using properties. Not only that, the answer is wrong, rider IDE does provide a refactor operation to convert properties into methods with accessors. There are many reasons why a developer would want this conversion and this question is a valid question.

Comment: The question itself is malformed and indeed opinion based but this hides a valid concern about a valid conversion. The 'correct' answer is also opinion based and misleading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A distinct non answer: stop wasting "double" your time!

C# isn't Java. Fighting a tool to fight the native idiomatic constructs of your target language, that is likely double pointless.

Source code is written to be read by humans. And good source code never surprises its readers. An experienced c# programmer will look at your Java like getters and setters and can only wonder: "why is he polluting these classes with those strange methods, instead of using c# property support".

Beyond that, you might want to read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle to understand why the c# properties are actually a *better* approach than Java fields with getter/setter pairs!

Or as they said 2 thousand years ago: when you come to Rome, do like the Romans do! If you don't want to do like the Romans do, stay away from Rome, or c# in your specific case.

Comment: C# isn't java indeed but properties also don't provide the same functionality as java getters and setters. You cannot chain property set calls and this is really annoying for providing a great single line usable builder pattern that works for immutable class updating (creating new instances).

Comment: @LucasMontenegroCarvalhaes As I have said; I do think that C# has an advantage here. But that isn't my point. I am merely talking about the fact that folks should be careful about turning language A into B.

Comment: This still hides the fact that a pattern exists and takes advantage of chaining setters, and that the IDE in question does have a feature that provides the getter/setter conversion functionality. So basically, although the question is badly written and the intention is incorrect, the answer is wrong an it is opinion-based.

Comment: The answer is perfect. Its based on the opinion of the language. A comment under the original question highlights the fact serializers could break if you do not follow C# conventions. Besides, chained setters for mutating an object isnt really attractive unless its a builder, in which case C# has a nice syntax for setting properties in an object the first time

Comment: @LucasMontenegroCarvalhaes "Source code shouldnt surprise the reader" isnt an opinion. It is a simple criteria to quickly determine the quality of source code. And note: my content starts with "a distinct non answer"; and the person asking the question accepted it.

Comment: I'll leave it there, I have said what I wanted to say. I still disagree with the answer but stack overflow offers tools for disagreement. C# ins't java was the opinion based quote that I was referring, not the property pattern. Everyone can code the way they need. I hope if someone finds this answer, at least they can refer to the comments for proper information. Yes, rider can convert properties into getters and setters.

Comment: "C# isn't java" ... is an opinion? Seriously? I think that is actually the most factual statement in my whole answer.

Answer (score 0):

OP is probably coming from the java world. In the Menu(Intellij) Java IDE ->Code->Generate 
[image: Generate]
In the generate menu, "Getter and Setter" is the 4th Option.
[image: Generate menu]
In the C# world(Rider), properties are used to expose selected fields.
Jetbrains [Recommends](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Generation__Properties.html) generating Properties rather than the Java getter-setter way. 
[image]

Comment: And these screen shots are from the c# ide? Because that rather looks like some Java tool,working Java source code in a Java project?!

Comment: Understand the question the Person is asking and answer it rather, than trying to answer a different question.. Yes That is from the jetbrains JAVA IDE.  Note that Following it I note Properties are better.

Comment: @AkinOkegbile the question is about C# code in Rider, which is a .NET IDE.

Comment: @OwenPauling The question is about a convention, getters and setters, which doesn't exist in C#. Jetbrains which makes the ide uses the same key combinations/menu options  across their IDE suite. 
I knew there would be a generate. In C# land, properties are what you SHOULD generate.